# Duplicate Content Issue with WordPress Permalink Structure and Primary Categories

Tags: permalinks, urls

I have  this permalink structure in wordpress **/%category%/%postname%/**

now suppose i have written a article article with title "Hello World"
and i selected two categories for this article **"cat1"** and **"cat2"**
now **"cat1"** is my **primary category** and i selected this using RankMath Plugin

just because **"cat1"** is my **primary category** for that post the url become

**https://example.com/cat1/hello-world/** when we go to this the post **"Hello World"** is loaded.

but when I manually go to the same post with "cat2" **https://example.com/cat2/hello-world/**
the same article "Hello World" is loaded.

Now  **https://example.com/cat1/hello-world/** & **https://example.com/cat2/hello-world/** both urls are working individually and this is a problem

this url with secondary category **https://example.com/cat2/hello-world/** should get 404 or automaticllay redirect to primary category url **https://example.com/cat1/hello-world/**

but the problem is if same post is working with "cat2" also

this way i have two url for same article, how to fix this? Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

```
function get_current_post_ID() {
    $postid = get_queried_object_id();
    $post_url = get_permalink( $postid );
    //wp_redirect( $post_url );
    if( has_category('', $postid) && urldecode('https://'.$_SERVER ['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER ['REQUEST_URI']) != $post_url ) :
        wp_redirect( $post_url, 308 );
        exit();
    endif;
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'get_current_post_ID' );
```